# Navigating dom to adjust custom jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, dom, accordion

I have the accordion working and it works really well as you go down the accordion, but as you come back up it's kinda glitchy.

I want to make it so when you click on a masthead it will open the content within that masthead and anchor the top of the page to the top of the masthead. I know what I need to do in pseudocode but am not sure about what to actually do with the code.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="made-insider.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div id="one" class="masthead"></div>
        <div class="insider-info"></div>

        <div id="two" class="masthead"></div>
        <div class="insider-info"></div>

        <div id="three" class="masthead"></div>
        <div class="insider-info"></div>

        <div id="four" class="masthead"></div>
        <div class="insider-info"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="made-insider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  //Checking the position of panels
  var allPanels = $('.insider-info').hide();

  //working accordion code -- needs to be smoother
  $('.accordion > .masthead').click(function(event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
            .next(allPanels).slideUp(400);
    } else {
      var topPos = $(this).position();
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
            .next(allPanels).slideUp(400);
      //if the previous accordion is open
        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: topPos.top - 200}, 600);
      //if the previous accordion is not open
        //$('body').animate({ scrollTop: topPos.top}, 600);
        $(this).addClass('active')
            .next(allPanels).slideDown(400);
    }
  });

});
```

I've tried things like

```
if ($(this).prev('.masthead').hasClass('.active')){
    behavior
}, 


if ($(this).prev().prev().hasClass('.active'){
    behavior
}

if ($(this).eq() < $('div.active').eq()){
    behavior
}
```

but none of them work. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the spot in your code where you need to know the index of `.active` runs after you remove class `.active` from whatever element currently has it.

Solution: Move this bit of code

```
$('.active').removeClass('active')
    .next(allPanels).slideUp(400);
```

to the end of the event handler, right before you add class `.active` to the new active element.

Then the condition you're looking for is

```
if ($('.active').length && $('.active').index() < $(this).index()) {
    // the previously active accordion is above the new one (we're moving down)
}
```

So, all together, you're code will look like this:

```
$('.accordion > .masthead').click(function (event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
            .next(allPanels).slideUp(400);
    } else {
        var topPos = $(this).position();

        // the previously active accordion is above the new one
        if ($('.active').length && $('.active').index() < $(this).index()) {
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: topPos.top - 200
            }, 600);
        } else { // the previously active accordion is below the new one, or there was no previous accordion
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: topPos.top
            }, 600);
        }

        $('.active').removeClass('active')
            .next(allPanels).slideUp(400);
        $(this).addClass('active')
            .next(allPanels).slideDown(400);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ywn2vhb/6/)

Comment: YES!! Thanks so much for your help, that's exactly what I was trying to do!!

Comment: Can I ask, what exactly is .length doing here?? Super happy it works, just curious what it's doing in this use case so I can learn!

Comment: Sorry, I should have put a better comment in for that.  It's just checking whether there is an active element.  If there is no panel currently open, we don't want to subtract 200 from the topPos, as that 200 is meant for accounting for the height of an open panel above the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I took a day this weekend to really clean up the code and improve the functionality of it as well.

This code will allow you to create an accordion that anchors to the top of the tab you click on and is made to be responsive to the both the size of the masthead tab and the content within the tab. Any suggestions on how I could make the code even cleaner would be awesome!

Check out the code on my GitHub, if you want: https://github.com/realjoet/smooth-flexible-accordion

```
$(function () {
  //Checking the position of panels
  var allContentPanels = $('.content');
  var allMastheads = $('.masthead');
  var hideContentPanels = allContentPanels.hide();
  //If you want margin on your mastheads, enter it here just like CSS
  var mastheadMargin = "0";
  //Need to fill these in with negative values of the values you put in for mastheadMargin
  var marginTopFix = "0";
  var marginRightFix = "0";
  var marginBottomFix = "0";
  var marginLeftFix = "0";

  allMastheads.css("margin", mastheadMargin);

  //working accordion code
  $('.accordion > .masthead').click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var activeEl = $('.active');
    var contentHeight = $('.active').next().height();
    var topPos = $(this).position().top;

    function marginFix(el) {
      $(el).next().css({
        "position": "relative", 
        "top": marginTopFix, 
        "right": marginRightFix, 
        "bottom": marginBottomFix, 
        "left": marginLeftFix
      }).delay(10);
    }

    //Accordion function
    function accordionFunc(el, animationTime, animationTime2) {
      if (el.hasClass('active')) {
        el.removeClass('active')
          .next(allContentPanels).slideUp(animationTime);
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: topPos}, animationTime);
      } else {
        if (activeEl.length && activeEl.index() < el.index()) {
          $('body').animate({scrollTop: topPos - contentHeight}, animationTime2);
        } else { 
          $('body').animate({scrollTop: topPos}, animationTime2);
        }

        activeEl.removeClass('active')
          .next(allContentPanels).slideUp(animationTime);
        el.addClass('active')
          .next(allContentPanels).slideDown(animationTime);
      }
    }

    //Adjusts masthead margins
    if (el.hasClass('active')) {
      marginFix(el);
      $(allMastheads).css("margin", mastheadMargin);
    } else {
      marginFix(activeEl);
      $(allMastheads).css("margin", mastheadMargin);
      el.css("margin", "0");
      el.next().css("margin", mastheadMargin);
      if (el.next().css("top") == marginTopFix) {
        el.next().css("top", "0");
      }
    }

    //Creates content-responsive accordion
    if (contentHeight < 400) {
      accordionFunc(el, 600, 800);
    } else if (contentHeight < 800) {
      accordionFunc(el, 800, 1000);
    } else if (contentHeight < 1200) {
      accordionFunc(el, 1000, 1200);
    } else {
      accordionFunc(el, 1200, 1400);
    }
  });
});
```